# Python intra-package reference not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.6
Simple package structure:

```
project/
  |-- main.py
  |-- package/
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- module1.py
      |-- module2.py
```

module1.py

```
import module2
```

main.py

```
from package import module1
```

Error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

Why is this not working? According to the Python Docs, the `import` statement should look for `module2` in the containing package.
How can I solve this without editing the `PATH`?

Comment: `from . import module2`. See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id9)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I still dont get WHY it doesnt work with absolute import?
Also, is this the same as writing `from package import module2` (which also works)?